# Mysql install issue in cloudformation json template

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have setup the codedeploy agent on my system and am looking to install all the user data from my cloudformation template while creating the ec2 instance. I access the EC2 instance by ssh and navigate to the `\home\ubuntu` folder. Now while installing mysql on ubuntu, a prompt appears to enter the password. I have worked around this since the prompts won't work with the template using this

```
"sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password \"\"' \n ",
"sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password \"\"' \n ",
"sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server \n ",
```

Here is my UserData parameter in my template:

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
        "#!/bin/bash -xe \n ",
        "cd /home/ubuntu \n ",
        "sudo apt-get update \n ",
        "sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y \n ",
        "sudo apt-get install ruby -y \n ",
        "sudo apt-get install wget -y \n ",
        "sudo apt-get install python -y \n ",
        "sudo apt-get update \n ",
        "sudo wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install \n ",
        "sudo chmod +x ./install \n ",
        "sudo ./install auto \n ",
        "sudo service codedeploy-agent start \n ",
        "sudo apt-get install tomcat8 -y \n ",
        "sudo echo \"JAVA_OPTS=\\\"\\${JAVA_OPTS} -Dspring.datasource.username=someusername -Dspring.datasource.password=somepassword -Dspring.profiles.active=aws\\\"\" >> /etc/default/tomcat8 ",
        "sudo echo ps ax | grep tomcat \n ",
        "sudo service tomcat8 restart \n ",
        "sudo apt-get update \n ",
        "sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password \"\"' \n ",
        "sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password \"\"' \n ",
        "sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server \n ",
        "sudo apt-get update \n "
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

All other components like tomcat, java etc are created successfully however the mysql server fails to install. Curiously, when I copy the user data from the AWS EC2 console and run it in my ec2 instance ssh, mysql server installs without any issues. The same code does not install mysql when I execute it from the template. Also, I tried installing mysql normally i.e. with just `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` but that too fails.
Any suggestions as to what is going wrong or what I could do differently?

Comment: what is the error that you see when the installation fails?

Comment: @krisnik There is no error as such. The instance is initiated successfully and shows as running. After that in my code-deploy agent, when I type in `mysql --version` it says `The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.7
 * mariadb-client-core-10.0`

Comment: Also when I pick up the same user data script from the AWS console and run it on the code-deploy agent, it executes successfully. This is really weird.

Comment: Yes, mysql-server installs server right? I am not sure if installs client as well. You should be able to access mysqld after mysql-server is installed.